# How could I parse carbon datetime object in Python and convert in another format

Tags: python, laravel

i am beginner in python coding. I have Laravel carbon datetime object which I need to convert into following format "Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z" in python language. Is there any library in python that can conver the laravel carbon object into another format using python object.

Carbon object received in python

```
    result = {dict: 3} {'date': '2020-09-25 10:58:11.812915', 'timezone_type': 3, 'timezone': 'UTC'}
 'date' = {str} '2020-09-25 10:58:11.812915'
 'timezone_type' = {int} 3
 'timezone' = {str} 'UTC'
 __len__ = {int} 3
```

Comment: Python has built in datetime,  you just need to import `from datetime import datetime`